# Why does my range breaker deliver 120 volts instead of 240?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm in Calgary Alberta and I added 2 afci breakers and 1 15amp breaker to my circuit as we are developing our basement. I moved 1 40amp range breaker and now I'm not getting 240v across the black and red. I do get 120v from white to red and white to black but 0v from black to red. I even tried a new breaker and still nothing.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Photo? Panel type or brand? It sounds like somehow the hots are on the same leg.

Comment: Thanks guys yeah didn't even think of putting the breaker on the same leg but that worked a treat. Cheers everyone

Comment: Adam, please have a look at how SE works, and resolve your question accordingly. http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess while we wait for details... You may have one of the rare panel brands that allows a dual breaker to be installed with both sides on the same leg of the panel. Try moving the breaker up or down one slot.

Comment: It's a federal pioneer stablock installed 5 years ago on 100 amp service. Will try moving the breaker. Will give more details in 10 min when I'm there

Answer (score 0):

The older federal pioneer stab locks had a really bad reputation, I thought they went out of business years ago. Look for burning at the breaker contact points, if all looks good try flipping the breaker on and off 10 times. If you now have power and there were no bad looking spots on the buss consider replacing the breaker. For your own information you should read up on these panels there have been many complaints of fires and malfunctioning breakers. Some say they are fine. Do your homework on this since you are upgrading you may want to replace the panel. Added link on [FPE breakers and panels](http://www.bankselectricllc.com/Panel_Upgrades/FPE%20PDF.pdf). Since you are in Canada your panel may be different than the ones in the U.S.

Comment: Tried changing the breaker yesterday still did the same no 240v both look in perfect condition. Will give that a try also. Thanks people.